# The test to aquire the Infinity Stone

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, infinity-stones

In *Avengers: Infinity War* we see the

> Soul Stone

requires a test be completed.  The other stones are already claimed by various parties, but were they originally hidden behind similar tests?  If not, do we know who set up the protections on this stone?

Comment: Did you *see* any of them requiring a test? (other than the strength to hold them)

Comment: @Möoz, not the same thing - after all, if someone other than Thanos had taken the Soul Stone from its hiding place (perhaps decades or centuries ago) and Thanos had stolen it from that person, we wouldn't have known about the Soul Stone test either.

Comment: That said, my guess is no: the Soul Stone is presumably the only one with any sort of understanding of good and evil, so it would be the only one that might consider a test necessary.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's my point ;-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston But they might not all be concerned with the user being good/bad, just worthy by whatever metric they embody.  For example, the Mind stone might have been locked behind some complex puzzle or the Power stone might have required feats of strength to first acquire.

Comment: @DavidStarkey, it isn't just a matter of what metric you measure worthiness by, I'm not sure the Mind stone would understand the concept of worthiness *at all*.  Also I wouldn't have thought any of the other stones would have *any* form of consciousness, but perhaps I've forgotten something to suggest that they do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Infinity War, the Guardian of the stone states that the Soul Stone is unique in that it requires a test.  I don't know the exact quote, but it is something like

> Unlike the other stones the Power of the Soul Stone requires a sacrifice, a soul for the Soul Stone

I think this shows that the other stones didn't need any kind of test to get them.

Comment: I had forgotten about this part, but why would the guardian of the soul stone know if the others initially had tests?  Perhaps it's just been too long since I've seen the movie he was last in.

Comment: The Guardian was given knowledge beyond his original understanding, he didn't know the original makeup of the tesseract before he became the guardian, he knows all who seek the soul stone, so I would suggest that of all beings he knows about the Infinity Stones. Also the idea that the stones needed to pass a test but then are free in the universe seems strange. I would expect the soul stone to return to Vormir when it is released by its holder. but that is my suposition

Comment: For safety's sake one would hope it goes someplace new, but agreed on the guardian's knowledge. He was pulled into a totally different stone, and speaks of the stones overall - it's safe to assume he got read in on some stuff when he was forcibly drafted to his job.